# Do I have to do fit PCA separately for train and test data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

I am considering to do PCA(TruncatedSVD) for reducing the number of dimension for my sparse matrix.

I split my data into train and test split.

```
X_train , X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
```

Do I have to do PCA seperatly for X_train and X_test?

```
pca = PCA()
X_train = pca.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = pca.fit_transform(X_test)
```

or Do I have to fit only on train data and then transform both train and test data. Which is preferred?

```
pca.fit(X_train)
train = pca.transform(X_train)
test = pca.transform(X_test)
```

EDIT:

I am doing a classification task. I have a column called `project_description` from my actual dataset and applied BoW (CountVectorizer) for that column and transformed it into count vectors and then applied PCA on it to reduce dimensions.

My Actual dataset also have other columns such as `price, place, date, share% etc...`

Now do I have to do apply PCA on my actual dataset(i.e other columns) before concatenating the PCA applied Bow Vector?

Comment: We *never* fit anything on the test set; `fit_transform` your training data, and then `transform` your test

Comment: The second case is preferable. Your test data shouldn't leak into any transformations you apply, hence you should only use training data to compute principal components.

Comment: If you are interested in a true generalization ability of your model you would fit on training data only and then apply fitted model to test.

Comment: @desertnaut I've updated the question with the doubt I had. Can you see if that helps to answer my query.

Comment: These are open-ended and very general questions that cannot really be answered generally (in contrast with your initial one); PCA is used for creating features, and in feature engineering, at least in theory, you can do *whatever you want* (i.e whatever gives better results to your specific problem)...

Comment: @desertnaut On Kaggle many people would be happy to fit their unsupervised models on both train and test. Never say *never*!

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov you do have a point, but Kaggle circumstances are rather special...

Comment: @desertnaut My point is the answer to OP depends on the circumstances

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov your point is clear, and it always does in principle; that said, if you are working in a real-world scenario (arguably the most "general" context) and you are interested in delivering a working model (rather than beating a metric, as in Kaggle), then you probably better act as if you don't have access at all to the test set...

Comment: @desertnaut 101% agree )))

Answer (score 0):

You should not do any preprocessing methods like dimension reduction, or normalization by using the whole dataset, Therefore:

- At first, you should split the dataset,
- Then you can standardize (or normalize based on your condition) the dataset by using only the train set
- After that, you can use the fitted scaler to transform the test set as well.
  If you want to apply dimension reduction methods like PCA, now you should:
- Perform PCA only on train set
- Then transform the test set as well
  (So only the second code that was mentioned in the question is correct.) 
  In this way, later we can use the test set to evaluate our model on unseen data points to see whether the model generalized well or not.

  ```
    # Split the dataset
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(X_array, 
                                                                 y_array, 
                                                                 test_size=0.3, 
                                                                random_state=42)  
    # Standardize the dataset                                             
    scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
    # Fit on the train set only
     scaler.fit(X_train)
     # Apply to both the train set and the test set. 
     X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
     X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
     # Apply PCA
     pca = PCA()
     # Fit on the train set only
     pca.fit(X_train)
     # Apply transform to both the train set and the test set. 
     X_train = pca.transform(X_train)
     X_test = pca.transform(X_test)
  ```